# AngularJS/UI/Bootstrap remove affix from an element?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, affix

I am using AngularJS 1.2 and Bootstrap 2.3, although I think it is irrelevant that Angular is involved since this is just jQuery.  I want to be able to turn the `affix` on and off for a particular element.  I have multiple elements on my page using `affix` so I can't just disable all instances of the plugin on the page.  Also, my problem is unrelated to screen sizes so css is not possible.

For an element for which I have added affix to:

```
$(element).affix();
```

Things I have tried that I read about online/stackoverflow to remove the affix, but have been unsuccessful:

```
$(element).off('.affix');

$(element).removeData('affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom');
```

Is it possible to just remove the affix aspect of this element?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.3 you use affix like this:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">...</div>
```

I would think you need to remove the `data-spy` attribute from an element

```
el = $(el);
var affixed = el.attr('data-spy');
if((typeof affixed != undefined) && (affixed !== false) && (affixed == 'affix'))
  el.removeAttr( "data-spy" );
```

Something like that I think would work.  Of course you could also remove the `data-offset...` attribute as well if there is one.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, as I am not adding the affix via an attribute on the div!  I just need to be able to turn the affix on and off via javascript. thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Add/remove your own 'sticky' class (or whatever you want to call it) when toggling between modes. Then, in the css, add the following style to your element:

`&:not(.sticky) {
    position: relative;
 }`

The bootstrap affix events will still continue to fire, but this will override the affix position:fixed style.